# Why did the Grievers not jump back on the cliff?

Tags: the-maze-runner

In the novel *The Maze Runner*, Thomas and Minho trick the Grievers into jumping off the cliff. The Grievers disappear(and we later learn their lair is actually invisible, just off the cliff edge). Why didn't the Grievers jump back and chase down Thomas and Minho?

It seems like the Creators purposefully spared Thomas/played favourites? Wouldn't this damage the Variables?

Comment: You may want to specify that this question is about the book. I've only seen it once but I'm pretty sure the film omits the Cliff and the invisible lair.

Comment: @Omegacron, you are correct.

Comment: @Omegacron I'm sorry, I haven't seen the movie. So I had no idea. Question edited.

Answer (score 2):

As the entire Maze and subsequent events are simply a "trial" in which the Gladers are tested and analyzed, the Creators have to try and keep it as real as possible. Thus, if something falls off the cliff, it probably shouldn't be able to turn around and jump out of nothingness back up onto the ledge. I'm sure the Creators have enough control to keep them from just leaping back out.

We also see after reading the rest of the series

> Thomas was their "favorite." They save him later when they really shouldn't have. He was the most promising subject, so they wouldn't want to let the Grievers kill him too easily, especially when he had managed such a feat as getting them to jump off of the cliff.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Griever's died from the fall.The second question does not apply because no one has ever thrown a Griever off of The Cliff before.I guess the Creators wouldnt want to kill someone who escaped four Griever's so intelligently.They wanted to find whether the people would escape not kill them.

Comment: No, we specifically know that they didn't die from the fall. They jump that way into the lair every morning. Moreover, they disappeared, unlike the stones which fell to the bottom of the cliff.